# Setting Variable Synchronously in Asynchronous Function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, return

```js
function foo()
{
 let a = 5;
 setTimeout(function(){a = 6;}, 1000);
 return a;
}
```

How can I return 6 for `foo`? The asynchronous function I am using is actually from a framework, not `setTimeout`.

Comment: That dupe is 90% relevant. They're using AJAX there, but the same answer applies regardless.

Comment: make a promise of it and use `async/await`

Comment: Would you mind answering it in code? I'm a beginner in JS. The other links I saw are too long.

Comment: I don't think you can. `console.log` is synchronous and _will_ log something immediately. It can't be delayed. Even by using `async/await`, it won't wait 1000ms before logging the value you're expecting. You can, however, log the value after it is changed from within the function.

Comment: @JeremyThille It's my bad. I don't need `console.log`, just the `return` value. I had added it here so it would display something when run.

Comment: The answer depends on the actual call. If it does not allow promises/async/await, there is not much you can do with that call. There might be other work arounds, but it all depends on the actual call. So the answer is dependent on the actual code. if it is not setTimeout, what is it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands you cannot make `foo` return the value of `a` as set within the callback given to `setTimeout` because when the return statement is executed the timeout callback function has not been invoked.

What you can do is make your function `async` and wrap the call to `setTimeout` in a Promise, then await that promise to allow the `setTimeout` callback to be invoked, and then finally return `a`.

```js
async function foo() {
  let a = 5;
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      a = 6;
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
  return a;
}

(async () => {
  console.log("running...")
  console.log(await foo());
})()
```